# Algorithm to check shape in matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I have a geoboard, and my application teaches mathematics to small kids. In geoboard we ask children to draw basic shapes like square, rectangle, triangle etc.

Geoboard:

[image]

Now to draw a square, there are various possibilities, like:

[image]

Or

[image]

Now the matrix which I get from above two are [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1] and [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]

So my question, is there any algorithm available which will help to decide whether the matrix has a square or any other basic shape?

Comment: Hmm.. Add all 1s, check if squared number?

Comment: It's not quite clear how the shape is represented. Must the squares be axis-aligned or would skew squares also count? What about the intermediate points on the edges between the corners, can these be omitted? For triangles, is the slope restricted to the eight principal directions or can it be arbitrary? It might be useful if you showed more examples of what you want to accept and what you want to reject.

Answer (score 0):

I can't name a specific algorithm but what I would do is convert the matrix into edges. Each edge would store its length and the angle of the next edge e.g. 90, 0, -30 degrees etc.. You would then check how many edges to see what shape it is then do a more specific search to make sure that for example all the angles are 90 degrees if you want to check if its a square.

I just realized your matrix is not enough to work out what shape was drawn because it only stores which points where travelled to, not the order. This means any number of shapes could have been drawn with say [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]. You will need to also store the order to do what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If all the shapes you're looking for are convex, you can plug in a convex hull algorithm. Once you calculate the convex hull of the shape you got, you first check if there are any 1s that are not on the boundary of the convex hull. If there are any, then the shape is wrong.

If there aren't, then you just count the number of edges and angles of your convex hull polygon, to tell you if it's a square, rectangle or triangle.